# add event listener not working for me

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

Im a beginner at javascript so sorry about the basic question. 
I wrote an event listener to call a function when a button is pressed. 
I cant get it to work.  As the code sits now, I am told by the interpreter 
that line 8, the addEventListener code, is not a function, and it does not work
on my page.  Any Ideas?  Thanks!

```
function createNewList() {

var displayNow = document.getElementById('listSectionMain');
displayNow.setAttribute('class', 'hideThis');
}

var butt = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonMain');
butt.addEventListener('click', function() {
createNewList() }
, false);
```

Comment: You should also show the HTML snippet of "buttonMain" and inner html. This will help to assist on narrowing in on the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line to

```
var butt = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonMain')[0];
```

Get elements by class name actually returns an array

EDIT:
This will work for your need.

```
var butt = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonMain');
for(i=0;i<butt.length;i++){
  butt[i].addEventListener("click", createNewList);
}
```

Comment: Did it work making that change?

Comment: Well I have more code to write to this function.  There are four total buttons that can be pressed and was hoping to write a switch statement for functionality depending on which button was pressed.  I understand my code returns an array, but thats ok right? I thought I was basically adding the event listener to all four buttons, then I would use an event object to find which button was pressed.

Comment: Check my edit, should handle what you need

Comment: Well, butt was perhaps a poor choice of wording. Good answer though.

Comment: Oh ok. so me trying to add multiple listeners wont work.  So this would loop through each and apply the property to each element.  Of course, thank you.

Comment: Please accept the answer...@DanielZuzevich butt.length :P giggle giggle

Comment: Everything worked except I had to remove the () from after the function call from the listener so the function would not just run, only when called.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array Array-like object

You could use it in this way...

```
function createNewList() {
    var displayNow = document.getElementById('listSectionMain');
    displayNow.setAttribute('class', 'hideThis');
}

var butt = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonMain');

butt[0].addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    alert ("Hello World!");
}
```

Here you go [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laktherock/yb00gzLn)

Comment: This actually would work for me, but the loop process fit my needs better.  Thank you for your help.